# Send user location to server(web file) even app is closed or terminated or kill for iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location

I want to sent the user current location to the server file every 5 minutes, in background its working

My question is how to using in the applicationWillTerminate even the app is closed or killed

```
var timer = Timer() 
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    timer.invalidate() // just in case this button is tapped multiple times

     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func timerAction() {

     //call the location manger to update the location to the server
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

//need code to call continuously  even app closed

}
```

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this.  You can't just track peoples location.

Comment: Is there any option to make the app as always running in background. Not allow user to close the app or if they close make the app as running in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far till now, Apple hasn't provided a facility to track user's location when app is inactive. So you can't track user's location when app is inactive or killed or terminated.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: Is there any option to make the app as always running in background. Not allow user to close the app or if they close make the app as running in background.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way. Refer this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075103/how-long-does-location-updates-process-can-run-in-background/46075470#46075470